# javascript not working in php file

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

There is a file index.php, in this file javascript is connected

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="uk">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Fiji Travel</title>
<link href="normalize.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="main/main.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="main/login.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald" rel="stylesheet">
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Arvo' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
</head>
<body>
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="center">
        <!-- Header -->
        <header>
            <h1>Fiji Travel</h1>
            <nav>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="/index.php" class="active">Main</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/blog/blog.php">Blog</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/gallery/gallery.php">Gallry</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/about/about.php">About</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/contacts/contacts.php">Contacts</a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
            <img src="../images/img02.jpg" alt="img02" class="slide">
        </header>
        <!-- Sidebar -->
        <?php require 'modules/sidebar.php'; ?>
        <!-- Content -->
        <main class="slide">
            <p>asdasd</p>
        </main>
    </div> <!-- end center -->
    <div class="clearfix"></div>
</div> <!-- end wrapper -->
<!-- Footer -->
<?php require 'modules/footer.php'; ?>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

I run the site through denwer. The problem is that the script in this file is not running.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(document).on("click", "a", function(e) {
        if ( $(this).hasClass('active') ) return;
        $("a").removeClass('active');
        $(this).addClass('active');
        $(".slide").slideUp(800);
        var self = this;
        setTimeout(function() {
            window.location.href = $(self).attr("href");
        }, 800);
    });
});
```

When the file was index.html, everything worked.
I tried to connect scripts with

```
<?php
echo ' <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>';
?>
```

, but it still doesn't work. I noticed that if the site hangs, then javascript starts working. How to solve this?

Comment: are you sure that script.js is located at the same folder with index.php? Open your browser console (ctrl_shift_I) and see if there is some error message in red color. (404 or 403 error message f.e.)

Comment: @nmnsud the .on method can be attached to 'document' just fine. Its not recommended, as it means every click will check for that event. Normally best to isolate the .on method to a smaller static block in the DOM.

Comment: @Qwerty when you say it all worked fine when it was index.html, but not when its index.php ... how are you outputting the html in your php? Your snippet excludes how your php is setup for output. Doing inline php, or echoing the whole block? Are you escpaing quotes correctly? Any php errors? Any console errors?

Comment: make sure your scripts are getting rendered properly with php. You can check console for possible warnings.

Comment: Are you unreservedly sure that your JavaScript code works fine on its own?

Comment: @Adam, I tested his code and it works. So the problem is with his server or paths.

Comment: only 1 yellow error in console "This page includes a password or credit card input in a non-secure context. A warning has been added to the URL bar."

Comment: i added index.php in question

Comment: @Randall, i added index.php in question

Comment: Just for testing... try to move your `require` to below the two `script` lines. Thinking maybe your php is halting on the require and outputting an incomplete html.

Comment: Maybe there is die() or exit() function somewhere in that PHP code.

Comment: @DawidLoranc I have no idea. There shouldn't be any hindrances when doing this.

Answer (score 0):

the error was in my js file. I forgot preventDefault()

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(document).on("click", "a", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    if ( $(this).hasClass(`active`) ) return;
    $("a").removeClass(`active`);
    $(this).addClass(`active`);
    $(".slide").slideUp(800);
    setTimeout(() => {
      window.location.href = $(this).attr("href");
    }, 800);
  });
});
```

Comment: more than two hours spent because of such nonsense)

Comment: I love that your setTimeout function is the only thing in ES6 haha.